# How to create an executable jar folder?

Tags: java, jar, heap-memory, executable

I am trying to create an executable jar file that a user can just click on and execute the code. I have done some research but almost all of the examples are for single files. I currently have all my classes and images being used in my files in a folder. My images exceed the default java memory space and thus I have to run my code with `-Xmx500m`.

How can I create an executable jar that will go into my folder and run my program from there? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just use jar command to create the jar. You may need to link this type of file to Java so that it can be run by clicking on it in Windows. Something like this-

```
jar cvf test.jar <path to your classes / resources>
```

Comment: This strategy will not provide 500 Meg of RAM for the app. to use.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create an executable jar file that a user can just click on and execute the code

Use [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to deploy it.

Put all the images and other media in Jar files mentioned in the launch file and they will be downloaded when needed.  JWS also has facilities to adjust the memory allocated to an app.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [https://netbeans.org/](https://netbeans.org/%22NetBeans%22) to build your project. Once built it will create the jar for you. You are also able to set compile settings such as the amount of ram you need.

See the following directions https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html#build